# Rails - capturing transaction id when saving a collection of child records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I save/update a project and its tasks I would like to be able to tell which tasks where saved in the transaction.  For example I might create the project with a few tasks initially, several hours later I might add more tasks.  I would like to know which tasks where create/updated in each transaction.  I could determine this by comparing created_at fields but that seems like a bit of a hack.

Any ideas?  Can I access the transaction object within the transaction and get a unique id from it?  That would be ideal.

Comment: What solution did you come up with?